# What software is available for 3D diagrams and graphs?

Tags: graphics

I'm looking for software to generate pretty 3D diagrams and graphics for scientific publications, for example something like this: http://www.123rf.com/photo_9355990_space-fill-ball-and-stick-models-of-methanol.html

Ideally, the software should also allow me to somehow allow me to place objects programmatically, if I would like 100s of spheres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't help with graphs, but for making molecular diagrams I highly recommend the open source [Jmol](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmol/), which is free for Windows, Mac, and Linux. It lets you create all sorts of molecules and export them as Java applets, images, or animations.

Comment: I managed to create my diagram with a PHP script, Jmol, and POVray.

Comment: @JakobEgger Glad my recommendation could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [MAPLE](http://www.maplesoft.com/) for this, since I already have it.  But of course it is **not cheap**<sup>TM</sup>